# angular 2 how to totals column ngFor?

Tags: angular

At the moment, I have several entries in the table. 
How can output one sum record of the total of all fields.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Total</th>
      <th>Done</th>
      <th>Not Done</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr *ngFor="let monitoring of monitorings">
     <td>{{monitoring.total}}</td>
     <td>{{monitoring.percent_done}}</td>
     <td>{{monitoring.percent_no_done}}</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

that is, I have here such records:

> 1) 
>   1.  Total = 3 Done = 100.0 % Not Done =   0.0 %
>   2. Total = 8 Done = 75.0 % Not Done =     25.0 %
>   3. Total = 2 Done = 100.0 % Not Done =    0.0 %
>   4.  Total = 2 Done = 100.0 % Not Done =   0.0 %
>   5. Total = 1 Done = 0.0 % Not Done =  100.0 %

And should output one record like this:

> 2)  Total = 16 Done =  81.25 % Not Done =     18.75 %

Comment: what you want get from there ... try to give more info on your question

Comment: @ganesh045 updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function in you component to get the sum and call it on ui something like

**in you component**

```
getTotal(arr){
  return arr.reduce( (sum, curr) => sum + curr.Total,0 );
}
```

**Then on ui**

```
   <tr *ngFor="let monitoring of monitorings">
     ....
   </tr>


 <tr><td>{{getTotal(monitorings)}}</td></tr>
```

This example is only for `Total` property same can be done for `Done,Not Done` etc

Comment: something I do not understand, I do the same thing and nothing is output at all

Comment: can you show what you tried also `arr.reduce( (sum, curr) => sum + curr.Total,0 );` to `return arr.reduce( (sum, curr) => sum + curr.Total,0 );` see updated answer

Comment: it does not sum them, but simply outputs them in one line and at the same time duplicates records(it turns out here such shnyaga: 02.01.08.02.03.0 )

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce read this also try changing to `return arr.reduce( (sum, curr) => sum + parseFloat(curr.Total),0 );`